# display name and contact number in my own list view using android 2.1

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts

i am trying to retrive all contact name and their number in my own list view. i am achive to get all name but when i am trying to get phone number too then it is going to display same number to me on every contact.

where number is getting value 1 from HAS_PHONE_NUMBER

my code is

```
if (number > 0) {
            Cursor phones = managedQuery(
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID , 
                         null, null);

startManagingCursor(phones);
             phones.moveToFirst();  

       String cNumber = phones.phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));  
       cache.nameView.setText(cache.nameBuffer.data, 0, size);
     cache.numView.setText(cNumber);
```

}

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        //get all contacts
        Cursor peopleCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);

        if(peopleCursor.getCount()>0)
        {  
            peopleCursor.moveToFirst();

            for(int i=0;i<peopleCursor.getCount();i++)
            {  
               if(check for HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)
               {
                   //get number
                   Cursor numberCursor=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID+"="+peopleCursor.getString(peopleCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)), null,null);
                   numberCursor.moveToFirst(); 

                   String number=numberCursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                   //get name
                   String name=peopleCursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

                   peopleCursor.moveToNext();                   
               }
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

u have to set While or for loop.In for code u used if basically it's used for condition that can't increment your value of number varable. **count total number of name u fetch**
it's variable name totalNumber_name

```
if (number == totalNumber_name) {
        Cursor phones = managedQuery(
                     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID , 
                     null, null);

startManagingCursor(phones);
         phones.moveToFirst();  

   String cNumber = phones.phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));  
   cache.nameView.setText(cache.nameBuffer.data, 0, size);
 cache.numView.setText(cNumber);
number++;
}
```

may be it's work

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it work fine in my App.

while (c.moveToNext())

```
    {
        contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        contactID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contactID },null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                contactTelNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            } 
        }

          Log.i("name ", contactName + " ");
        Log.i("number ", contactTelNumber + " ");
```